# Creating button on corona using one line) but adding the function fails

Tags: mobile, sdk, lua, coronasdk

Been researching but no luck. Creating a button on Corona SDK requires several lines. ([Corona SDK reference here](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newButton.html)). If you create 5 buttons the code grows a lot, so I created a function that I can call with just one liner and creates the buttons I need. It works fine but can't sort the events.

```
cbutton = function (nbutton, tbutton, blabel, bfs, bx, by)

bfcolor={default = { 51, 51, 51, 215 }}
if tbutton == "default-1" or tbutton == "default-2" or tbutton == "default-3" then bfcolor = nil end

local button1 = widget.newButton
{
    defaultFile = "assets/" .. tbutton .. ".png",
    overFile = "assets/o" .. tbutton .. ".png",
    label = blabel,
    labelColor = bfcolor,
    fontSize = bfs,
    emboss = true,
    onPress=botonhrPress // <-- HERE, THIS PART
}
button1.x = bx; button1.y = by
end


cbutton("b1","primary-1","Create account", 20, 160, 160)
```

So, here is the thing.

1. The code above works, it creates the button.
2. Using the last line, calls the function and creates the button
3. It used the parameters
4. The part that says "HERE" works, ties the event to the button
5. BUT, it's directly written, can't pass parameters there

Tried concatenation, a full string variable with the name of the local function, also %, &, () and {} to enclose the data, no luck. If we can work around this part then we could create buttons with just one line of code + the function posted here. Any ideas will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: My code builds buttons as the Twitter Bootstrap framework (graphics), that's why the options to use primary, default, success, etc.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Do you want the `onPress` callback to be passed as a parameter? Are you looking for a way to pass some of the parameters to `botonhrPress`? `botonhrPress` isn't defined anywhere, what is it, what do you want it to do?

Comment: Sorry for not making it easier. The function is defined above (or wouldn't work in Corona), the button function (event) is defined inside but it's hand written, I need to put there a variable or something that allows me to call the whole function defining custom event functions for the button. So far it doesn't work except is hand written.

Comment: Trying to be clearer: I can set all the values of the whole function via parameters except the event listener for the button, the variables are not being accepted. The whole idea is to write that thing just once and call it multiple times, thanks.

Comment: I still am not sure what the problem is, a function can be passed as an argument as well. You can add `botonhrPress` as a parameter to your `cbutton` function.

Comment: I will try again: the function creates a button, it's been placed as a function that can be called and pass parameters so one function can create several diff buttons. All the options are passed as parameters but the event for the button can't. This means using that function to create 5 buttons ends up with all of them calling the same event, I'm looking for ways to work around that.

Comment: Addressing the problem:

var name = "john" it works as placed inside the function so I can pass parameters to it.
BUT the name of the function doesn't accept variables, that's the problem

Comment: you can create a new function that encapsulates though parameters, "a closure"

Comment: can you tell me what are parameters you want to pass ?